# Как складывается 2 числа на уровне процессора?

Tags: теория, процессор

Стало интересно, каким образом процессор складывает 2 числа? Допустим у нас есть 2 числа в двоичном коде: 00000001 и 00000010. Что процессор делает, чтобы получилось 00000011?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: У Вектозавра было обалденное видео на эту тему https://youtu.be/Cp4fI_i60No . Он вообще много забавных видео снимал, поясняя на пальцах как что-то работает.

Comment: @EugeneX спасибо